# Specialization of 'template<class _Tp> struct std::less' in different namespace

Tags: c++

I am specializing the 'less' (predicate) for a data type.

The code looks like this:

```
template<>
struct std::less<DateTimeKey>
{
   bool operator()(const DateTimeKey& k1, const DateTimeKey& k2) const
   {
      // Some code ...
   }
};
```

When compiling (g++ 4.4.1 on Ubuntu 9.10), I get the error:

Specialization of 'template struct std::less' in different namespace

I did some research and found that there was a 'workaround' which involved wrapping the specialization in a std namespace - i.e. changing the code to:

```
namespace std {
template<>
struct less<DateTimeKey>
{
   bool operator()(const DateTimeKey& k1, const DateTimeKey& k2) const
   {
      // Some code ...
   }
};
}
```

which indeed, shuts the compiler up. However, that solution was from a post 5 years old (By the 'great' Victor Bazarof no less [pun unintended]). Is this fix still the way to go, or is there a better way of resolving this, or is the "old way" still valid?

Comment: Overload `DateTimeKey::operator<`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is still the way to do it. Unfortunately you cannot declare or define functions within a namespace like you would do with a class: you need to actually wrap them in a namespace block.

Answer (score 26):

If you need to specialize a standard algorithm, you can do so in the std namespace. It is the only thing that you are allowed to do inside that namespace according to the standard.

> [lib.reserved.names]/1
>
> It is undefined for a C++ program to
>   add declarations or definitions to
>   namespace std or namespaces within
>   namespace std unless otherwise
>   specified. A program may add template
>   specializations for any standard
>   library template to namespace std.
>   Such a specialization (complete or
>   partial) of a standard library
>   template results in undefined behavior
>   unless the declaration depends on a
>   user-defined name of external linkage
>   and unless the specialization meets
>   the standard library requirements for
>   the original template

Now, the question is whether you actually want to specialize `std::less`. Note that `std::less` will call the comparison operator defined for your type, so you can provide that operation instead of specializing the template.

The problem with specializing `std::less` for your particular type is that it will cause confusion if you provide a different operation than the one performed by `operator<` for your type. If they perform the same operation, just leave the default `std::less` definition without specialization.

If you do not want to provide the comparison operator, but still want to use the type in associative containers or with algorithms that require a comparator, you can provide an external comparison functor by other name that will not confuse other readers (and yourself somewhere in the future).

Answer (score 4):

Why are you even doing this?

`std::less` exists for two purposes only:

1. to give a name to operator <, allowing it to be passed as a functor
2. to explicitly allow comparing two pointers that aren't in the same array (which is technically illegal if done with raw pointers)

There's no reason for a user to overload it - either overload `operator<` or use a custom comparator function.

There are std algorithms that can be sensibly specialized - `std::swap` is a good example - and to do so you do need to declare the specialization inside namespace std.

Comment: I'm not sure std::swap is a good example, since the smart money is that you don't specialize it, you define an independent `swap` function in the same namespace as the UDT, and let ADL find it. The exception I can think of is if your class has to work with a template which never got that memo, and which calls `std::swap(t1,t2)` instead of `using std::swap; swap(t1,t2);`. Not sure whether this is sensible specialization, or merely pragmatic specialization ;-)

Comment: There's been much discussion on the boost mailing lists about which is best, which is why boost::swap picks up either.

Comment: `std::less` exists for a third reason: Sometimes, a type's `operator<` behaves slightly strangely. The prime example is floating point numbers where one may want to treat `-0.0` different from `0.0`, or where one may want to make `nan` comparable. Other examples are types that only have a partial order, and where the `<` notation is a natural domain-specific notation. In these cases, specializing `std::less` allows using this type in sets and maps.

Comment: @Erik Schnetter: In those cases you should use a custom comparator. Specializing `std::less` to not behave like `operator <` vioaltes the principle of least surprise.

Comment: @JoeGauterin <http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less> says: "The partial specialization of std::less for any pointer type yields a total order, even if the built-in operator< does not."

Comment: I have had the case where I want more than one map sorted in different ways and being able to specify a "custom" comparitor is is desirable for this.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the question has been answered by others with answers on how to specialize `std::less` (by wrap them in a namespace block) and the right way to do it ( to overload `operator <`).

However, `C++` now allows (in `C++11`) to speciliaze the way you did in your first example.

> An explicit specialization shall be declared in a namespace enclosing the specialized template. An explicit specialization whose declarator-id is not qualified shall be declared in the nearest enclosing namespace of the template, or, if the namespace is inline (7.3.1), any namespace from its enclosing namespace set. Such a declaration may also be a definition. If the declaration is not a definition, the specialization may be defined later (7.3.1.2).

I tried the following code with `g++ (8.3.0)` on my `Ubuntu` machine.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>


class myType {

public:
    myType(int in): i_(in) { }

    int i_;
};

template <>
struct std::less<myType>  {
    bool operator()(const myType& a, const myType& b) const
    {
        return a.i_ < b.i_;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::map<myType, std::string> vector = { { 1, "1"}, { 2, "2"}, { 3, "3"}, { 0, "0" } };

    for (auto& i: vector)
        std::cout << i.first.i_ << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code was compiled with

```
g++ --std=c++11 compare.cpp -Wall
```

Answer (score 1):

The less functor doesn't have to be in **`std`** namespace. So

```
struct A
{
    A(int _v=0):v(_v){}
    int v;
};


template<>  struct less<A>
{
    bool operator()(const A& k1, const A& k2) const
    {
        return k1.v < k2.v;
    }
};


std::map<A,int> m;
m[A(1)] = 1;
m[A(2)] = 2;
```

Works as expected. (Calls the functor you just created).

I guess you already know, but you can just write your own operator<(k1,k2), which is what default less functor looks for.

```
bool operator<(const DateTimeKey & k1, const DateTimeKey & k2)
{
//your code...
}
```

Comment: nope, it does have to be in std. that `less` struct has no main template. clang says `error: no template named 'less'; did you mean 'std::less'?`

Comment: Yes, has to be in std::. either wrap it in std:: or use std::less as mentioned above.