# STL less operator and "invalid operator<" error

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, strict-weak-ordering

I have some code that compiles fine in VS 10.0 but after inserting a few items into the Orders map below I receive an "invalid operator <" error in Microsoft debug library. My less operator is simple, just compares the 8 byte string char by char. Anyone have any idea why I would receive this error?

```
typedef struct MY_orderID_t
{
    char orderID[8];
} MY_orderID_t;

struct std::less<MY_orderID_t>
{ 
   bool operator()(const MY_orderID_t& k1, const MY_orderID_t& k2) const
   {
       for( int i=0; i < 8; i++ )
       {
           if( k1.orderID[i] < k2.orderID[i] )
           return( true );
       }
       return( false );
   }
};

std::map< MY_orderID_t, MY_order_t > Orders[5];
```

Answer (score 27):

I believe that the problem here is that your method of comparing two `MY_orderID_t`'s is not a **[strict weak order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering)**, the type of ordering relation required by the C++ STL.  To be a strict weak order, your less-than operator must have the following four properties:

1. **Irreflexivity**: x < x is always false.
2. **Antisymmetry**: If x < y, then y < x is always false.
3. **Transitivity**: If x < y and y < z, then x < z is always true.
4. **Transitivity of Equivalence**: If x and y are incomparable and y and z are incomparable, then x and z are incomparable.

Right now, your ordering doesn't obey properties (2) or (3).

*First, (2) is violated by the following:

```
(0, 4) < (2, 2) 
(2, 2) < (0, 4)
```

*Second, (3) is violated, because

```
(0, 1) < (2, 0) < (-1, 1)

// but 

(0, 1) < (-1, 1) // Fail
```

To fix this, instead of using the comparison you currently have, instead use a **[lexicographical comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_ordering)** like this one:

```
return std::lexicographical_compare(k1.orderID.begin(), k1.orderID.end(),
                                    k2.orderID.begin(), k2.orderID.end());
```

This comparison is a strict weak ordering and is what's used by all the STL containers by default.  Switching to this comparison obeys properties (1) - (4) and should cause everything to work correctly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: For further details, see this excellent article: [Order I Say!](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2010/02/order-i-say/).

Answer (score 5):

@templatetypedef tells you what's wrong with your current version.

Here's a much more readable fix:

```
struct MY_orderID_type
{
    char orderID[8];
    bool operator<(const MY_orderID_type& other) const
    { return memcmp(orderID, other.orderID, 8) < 0; }
};

std::map< MY_orderID_type, MY_order_type > Orders;
```

Answer (score 3):

@templatetypedef addresses the requirements for a `std::less` specialization to be used with `map`, from a purely syntactical point of view:

- You need to `#include` `<functional>` and `<map>`
- You are missing `}` between `char    orderID[8];` and `MY_orderID_t;` on the next line.
- and:

  ```
  struct std::less<MY_orderID_t>
  {
       /* ... */
  };
  ```

  should be:

  ```
  namespace std {
  template <>
  struct less<MY_orderID_t>
  {
      /* ... */
  };
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Besides any other possible errors, which I don't see at the moment, this construct is not allowed:

```
struct std::less<MY_orderID_t>
{ /**/ }
```

`std::less` is already a type, so you cannot redefine it as another type.

Comment: And [this other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282349/specialization-of-templateclass-tp-struct-stdless-in-different-namespace) shows the right way to specialize `std::less`.