# how to compare structs

Tags: c++

I am having difficulties to set up the comparison correctly.
Here is an example of my problem, where my code wrongly assumes {1,2}={2,1}: http://ideone.com/i7huL

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct myStruct {
  int a;
  int b;
  bool operator<(const myStruct& rhs) const {
           return rhs.a < this->a && rhs.b < this->b;
  }
};


int main() {
       std::map  <myStruct, int> mymap ;
       myStruct m1={1,2};
       myStruct m2={2,1};
       mymap.insert(make_pair(m1,3));
       std::map<myStruct, int>::iterator it1 = mymap.find(m1);
       std::map<myStruct, int>::iterator it2 = mymap.find(m2);
       cout << it1->second << it2->second;
       // here it1->second=it2->second=3, although I would have expected it2 to be equal to map.end().
}
```

I could use || instead of &&, but I'm not sure this is the correct way either. I just want to have operator< implemented in such a way that I am able to find objects in my map, without making any errors, as is the case in the code I linked to.

Thanks.

Comment: well the argument is called rhs for a reason ... right hand side. but you currently test rhs < lhs. See the problem?

Comment: You're right, there's a slight mistake there. Does it matter though ? It's just that the order of everything is inverted, but it doesn't explain why {1,2}={2,1}, or does it?

Comment: No it doesn't matter. But i think your problem is not a real problem, just a design descision. You need to clearly define when MyStruct is "smaller" than another one. Does smaller means "both member are smaller" "either member are smaller" "the first member is smaller" its up to you and what you need it for.

Comment: The thing is that I don't really care to know when one is smaller or greater than another, I just want to be able to find myStruct objects in mymap. The problem is that when defined in this way, I can't find them, the find() makes errors, as you can see. So how to define operator< properly ?

Comment: Hans Passant has already given you the correct answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [stl less operator and "invalid operator<" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040689/stl-less-operator-and-invalid-operator-error)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this operator implementation doesn't make much sense.  I'd recommend:

```
  bool operator<(const myStruct& rhs) const {
      return rhs.a < this->a || (rhs.a == this->a && rhs.b < this->b);
  }
```

Comment: This seems quite complicated. Could you explain the idea behind it, and how to expand it to say, 4 int members within myStruct ?

Comment: @NaomiJO, Then just check if a<rhs.a, or if they're equal, b<rhs.b, if they're equal then c<rhs.c and so on.

Comment: Well that's what I tried to do with my own definition. How does it differ ?

Comment: @NaomiJO, Yours is backwards.

Comment: Read it out loud, and it should be clearer. "If rhs.A is smaller than lhs.A OR rhs.B is smaller than lhs.B" is different from "If rhs.A is smaller than lhs.A OR rhs.A is equal to lhs.A and rhs.B is smaller than lhs.B"

Comment: @chris, yes, but dowhilefor and I agreed that it being backwards doesn't really matter.

Comment: @NaomiJO sry, i didn't mean it doesnt matter. I just meant thats not the problem at hand. It still matters, because A < B != B < A

Comment: It all depends on how you want to order the structs.  Which you didn't explain in the question.  The example I gave is a very common one, that's how you sort names in a phone book for example.  Last name is most important, first name is less important.  Only if the last names are equal do you order by the first name.  Apply the rule you used to a phone book example and see what happens.

Comment: Further reading material: [Order I Say!](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2010/02/order-i-say/)

Comment: this "answer" appears to be backwards with "rhs < lhs" which is the same as "lhs > rhs"...for the less than operator.

Answer (score 8):

```
bool operator<(const myStruct& rhs) const {
  if (a < rhs.a) return true;
  if (a == rhs.a) return b < rhs.b;
  return false;
}
```

If you are looking for a generalization to many data members, there is a great example using C++11 [std::tie](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie):

```
struct S {
    int n;
    std::string s;
    float d;
    bool operator<(const S& rhs) const {
        return std::tie(n, s, d) < std::tie(rhs.n, rhs.s, rhs.d);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your operator does not define a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering).  Think through your how your example of `{1,2}` and `{2,1}` would go down in your operator.  Assume `X = {1,2}`, and `Y = {2,1}`.

Is X < Y? Is 1 < 2 *AND* 2 < 1? No, therefore X is not less than Y.

Is Y < X? Is 2 < 1 *AND* 1 < 2? No, therefore Y is not less than X.

So, if X is not less than Y, and Y is not less than X, what's left?  They're equal.

You need to pick one of the members of your struct, either `a` or `b` to be the primary comparison.  If the primary comparison results in equality, only *then* do you check the secondary comparison.  Just like when you [alphabetize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) something.  First you check the first letter, and only if they are equal do you go on to the next.  Hans Passant has provided an example of this.

Here's a more serious problem example for your operator.  The one I gave above is not *necessarily* bad, because maybe you *want* `{1,2}` to be considered equal to `{2,1}`.  The fundamental problem crops with a set of values like this: consider `X = {1,1}, Y = {1,2}, Z = {2,2}`

With your operator, X is definitively less than Z, because 1 is less than 2.  But X comes out equal to Y, and Y comes out equal to Z.  In order to adhere to strict weak ordering, if X = Y, and Y = Z, then X should equal Z.  But here that is not the case.

Answer (score 3):

You asked about generalising to four int members, here's how I would structure such code for maximum clarity.

```
bool operator<(const myStruct& rhs) const
{
  if (a < rhs.a)
    return true;
  if (a > rhs.a)
    return false;
  if (b < rhs.b)
    return true;
  if (b > rhs.b)
    return false;
  if (c < rhs.c)
    return true;
  if (c > rhs.c)
    return false;
  if (d < rhs.d)
    return true;
  if (d > rhs.d)
    return false;
  return false;
}
```

You can easily extend such code for as many data members as you wish.

Comment: Replacing `a > rhs.a` with `rhs.a < a` would have the minor benefit of only requiring `operator<()` from the member classes.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution uses `std::tie` to compare the tuples.

```
return std::tie(rhs.a, rhs.b) < std::tie(a, b);
```

This generalizes very quickly and simply to more data members.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to write this by comparing elements for equality until two are found that are different:

```
bool operator<(const myStruct& rhs) const {
    if (a != rhs.a)
        return a < rhs.a;
    if (b != rhs.b)
        return b < rhs.b;
    return false; // this and rhs are equal.
}
```

I find this clearer and more extensible than writing a single expression with a mix of || and && (as per @HansPassant), and more compact than @jahhaj's approach of having each passing test lead to a `return true;` or `return false;`. Performance is about the same, unless you know something about the distribution of values. There is an argument for avoiding `operator==()` and just using `operator<()`, but that only applies if you are trying to write maximally generic template code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you need to know what your structure represents. Otherwise defining a < operator would just become arbitrary. Others won't be able to give you a fitting answer. Take an example where when your structure represents a cartisian coordinate of a point in 2D. In this case you could define a meaningful ordering operator such as the distance from the origin for the structure.

i.e, distance d1 = this->a*this->a + this->b*this->b
distance d2 = rhs.a*rhs.a + rhs.b*rhs.b
if(d1 < d2)
  return true;
else
  return false;