# Is it safe to use operator != as operator < in a std::set?

Tags: c++, algorithm, set

I have a struct with some members and I have an implemented operator== for it. Is it safe to implement the operator< with the help of operator==? I want to use this struct in a set, and I want to check that this struct is unique.

```
struct Data
{
  std::string str1;
  std::string str2;
  std::string str3;
  std::string str4;

  bool operator==(const Data& rhs)
  {
    if (str1 == rhs.str1
     && str2 == rhs.str2
     && str3 == rhs.str3
     && str4 == rhs.str4
       )
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }

  // Is this ok??
  bool operator<(const Data& rhs)
  {
    return !this->operator==(rhs);
  }
}
```

So when I insert this struct to a std::set what will happen?

Comment: Your comparison function should satisfy strict weak ordering http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html. You should ask yourself, does my comparator provide this behavior ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope, it's quite unsafe. The simplest way to implement it is through `std::tie`.

```
#include <tuple>
struct Data
{
  std::string str1;
  std::string str2;
  std::string str3;
  std::string str4;

  bool operator<(const Data& rhs) const // you forgot a const
  {
      return 
      std::tie(str1, str2, str3, str4) < 
      std::tie(rhs.str1, rhs.str2, rhs.str3, rhs.str4);
  }
}
```

Comment: std::tie is C++11 specific and I can not use it

Comment: How about `std::tr1::tie` or `boost::tie` then? How old is your compiler?

Comment: Thx, I will try it. I use gcc 4.6.3 for linux and MSVC2010 on Windows

Comment: Both of those compilers should support `<tuple>` and `std::tie`.

Answer (score 6):

No, that is not safe. The way you've defined `<`, `a < b` and `b < a` will both be true at the same time.

> So when I insert this struct to a std::set what will happen?

The behaviour is undefined, so anything is permitted, and it will likely be different on different implementations.

Comment: @JohnDibling The behaviour of that `operator<` is defined but wrong, the behaviour of using that `operator<` for a set is undefined. A set requires that if `a < b` returns true, `b < a` returns false, and if your `operator<` does not satisfy that requirement, one realistic possibility is that some methods of the set result in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

Well your code suggests that if `A!=B`, that means that `A<B` which is definitely wrong, since it can as well be `A>B`.

You will have to implement your `>` and `<` operators the same way you did with the `operator==`, which means by comparing the objects member-wise. It's up to you to decide how to determine if `A` is "more" or "less" than `B` based on their members.

If you use the operator as you have it in any of the standard library containers, you will get UB.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `operator<` in its own terms.  You cannot implement `operator<` in terms of `operator==`, although you may be able to do the reverse.

Consider the paradox in this truth table:

```
"a" < "b" : TRUE
"b" < "a" : TRUE
```

If your implementation of `operator<` yields the above paradox, which it does if you implement it in terms of `operator==` then you have not correctly implemented strict weak ordering.  What you've implemented is a jumbled mess.

You need to determine which of the member strings take precedence over the others, and then perform a comparison between them in order -- from most important to least important.

For example, if the precedence of the string is, from most important to least important:

1. `str1`
2. `str2`
3. `str3`
4. `str4`

...then this yields the following algorithm for `operator<`:

```
bool operator<(const Data& rhs) const
{
  if( str1 < rhs.str1 )
    return true;
  if( rhs.str1 < str1 )
    return false;
  if( str2 < rhs.str2 )
    return true;
  if( rhs.str2 < str2 )
    return false;
  if( str3 < rhs.str3 )
    return true;
  if( rhs.str3 < str3 )
    return false;
  if( str4 < rhs.str4 )
    return true;
  if( rhs.str4 < str4 )
    return false;

  return false;
}
```

Using this, you could optionally next re-implement `operator==` in terms of `operator<`.  You assume the inherent inefficiency of time complexity in doing so, however:

```
bool operator==(const Data& rhs) const
{
  return !operator<(rhs) && !rhs.operator<(*this);
}
```

Comment: I found a similar topic, where there is a similar solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11703971/534381 But it is a little different... Which is better?

Comment: The linked one is better because I forgot to consider the case where "c,a" should not be considered < than "a,b".  I will adjust my answer.

Comment: Yes, your solution is perfect. But std or boost tie is simpler.