# c++ std::set equality

Tags: c++, set, compare, equals

I try to use a `std::set` in order to have unique elements in my container.

Since I have 3D objects :

```
Class Object3D{  
 private:  
  float x;  
  float y;  
  float z;  
}
```

Those objects are equal when    `(A.x==B.x && A.y==B.y && A.z==B.z)`.
In std::set implementation a element    `A==B if (!(A < B) && !(B>A))`.
It's impossible for my comparison... I have tried to overload `==` operator.
I chose set container for comparing values when I call `insert(a)`. 
I was doing something like that with `std::vector v` and his iterator:

```
if(!(A).inVector()){
 v.push_back(A);
}
```

With

```
bool inVector(){
 for(itr = v.begin();itr != v.end();itr++){
  if(this->x==(*itr)->x && this->y==(*itr)->y && this->z==(*itr)->z){
   return true;
  }
 }
 return false;
}
```

Checking it for each object (10000-100000) is expensive in complexity.
Can someone have an idea ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782225/is-it-safe-to-use-operator-as-operator-in-a-stdset has a similar discussion that might help you.

Comment: You can provide your own comparator function, it needs not neccessarily be less-than operator. It has to obey [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html), though. The definition of equality then becomes `!comp(A,B) && !comp(B,A)` for a comparator function `comp`.

Comment: yeah, note to OP: `A==B if (!(A<B) && !(B>A))` should be `A==B if (!(A<B) && !(B<A))`

Answer (score 7):

You need to implement a strict weak ordering `<` for your class. The easiest way is to use the lexicographic ordering provided by `tuple`:

```
#include <tuple>

class Object3D
{
public:
    bool operator<(Object3D const & rhs) const
    {
        return std::tie(x, y, z) < std::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y, rhs.z);
    }

    // ...
};
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be `operator<`.  Nor should it.  The OP is correct that it doesn't really make sense for one object to be considered less than another based on some arbitrary decisions about the relative significance of the x, y and z coordinates.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Well, it makes sense as the lexicographic ordering of tuples of individually ordered things. And since there's no "geometric" ordering on the OP's domain anyway, there's no danger of confusion. If you prefer, you can specialize `std::less<Object3D>`, of course. But then you need to mess with friendship. One thing at a time, eh?

Answer (score 5):

@OP: `std::set` is a unique, ordered container. It requires either an `operator<` or a comparator passed explicitly, which implements a strict weak ordering.

If you *don't want* to impose an ordering on your elements, *don't* use an ordered container. You can use `std::unordered_set` if you just want to detect uniqueness without imposing an ordering.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a comparator.  You don't want to implement `operator<`, and I agree with that decision.  You shouldn't provide meaningless functions for your class just to satisfy the constraints of some container.  Thankfully, you don't need `operator<`.  But you do need a function that has behavior similar to `operator<`.  It doesn't have to *mean* that one object is considered less than another.  It just needs to provide a strict-weak ordering.  You can give it any name you want.  For example:

```
bool Compare_by_x_then_y_then_z(const Object3D& lhs, const Object3D& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.getX() != rhs.getX()) return lhs.getX() < rhs.getX();
    if (lhs.getY() != rhs.getY()) return lhs.getY() < rhs.getY();
    return lhs.getZ() < rhs.getZ();
}
```

You then provide this function to the constructor of your set:

```
typedef bool(*compT)(const Object3D&, const Object3D&);
std::set<Object3D,compT> objects(Compare_by_x_then_y_then_z);
```

Comment: This solution is superior. Thanks a lot, just used this at my job today after hours of trying to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

You *have* to provide a comparison operator, because `std::set` needs it for its implementation.

A simple less-than operator would look like this:

```
bool Object3D::operator<(const Object3D& other) const {
    if(x != other.x) return x < other.x;
    if(y != other.y) return y < other.y;
    return z < other.z;
}
```

Comment: You should make that function const.

Comment: Sure but what does it mean for points ? How a point can be less than an other except by distance, but in this case my equality contraint doesn't match.

Comment: @user1788477: It doesn't have to be `operator<`.  You can make a global function and name it any thing you want, and provide that as an additional template argument for your set.  So it doesn't have to mean that one point is less than another.  It just needs to provide some way to order them.

Comment: @user1788477 - `set` is ordered, so you have to provide some ordering. If you don't want to order your points, don't use `set`.

Answer (score 1):

You must declare operator<. You can do it like this

```
bool operator<(const Object3D& a, const Object3D& b)
{
    if (a.x < b.x) return true;
    if (b.x < a.x) return false;
    if (a.y < b.y) return true;
    if (b.y < a.y) return false;
    if (a.z < b.z) return true;
    if (b.z < a.z) return false;
    return false;
}
```

It is arbitrary, but it doesn't really matter. As long as operator< gives a consistent ordering you'll be OK.

Comment: No it couldn't, as that would give it a change to return true at one of the later tests.