# Lambda key comparator for map

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement my own key comparator for std::map as follows:

```
auto cost_compare = [](const OffsetCoords& left, const OffsetCoords& right) { 
return (left == right); };

std::map<OffsetCoords, int, decltype(cost_compare)> cost_so_far(cost_compare);
```

where `OffsetCoords` is struct, vector of x, y values with overloaded `operator==`

code builds fine, but when I call `cost_so_far.count(some_offsetcoords_variable)` it throws exception 'Expression: invalid comparator'.

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Map needs less-than.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040689/stl-less-operator-and-invalid-operator-error

Comment: This question fails to meet the requirements for a [mcve], and therefore cannot be answered.

Comment: @RichardCritten: actually it doesn't. Using the less-than operator is an easy way to provide the binary predicate because `std::less<Key>` is used by default. You can use other binary predicates. However, the predicate used has to implement a _strict weak order_. In math, the symbol used to indicate the canonical strict weak order happens to be `<`. Where the choice of predicate matters, different symbols may be used, e.g., when any suitable strict weak order can be used the symbol is often a less-than within a circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binary predicate `Comp` used for `std::map<Key, Value, Comp>` needs to implement a [*strict weak order*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) on objects of type `Key`. the *strict* refers to the fact that `comp(x, x)` yields `false` for all objects of type `Key` used with `Comp`. For the predicate you defined that is *not* the case.