# Implement sort with templates. How to use comparator?

Tags: c++, templates, sorting, compiler-errors

I'm implementing a simple sort algorithm just to learn how C++ templates work.
I need to sort arrays with elements of different types, so I need to use different functions of comparing them. For example, I want to sort the array of football players by their efficiency. I've written functor in with structure and use it in this way:

```
 insertionSort(players, 0, players.size() - 1, Player());
```

But in insertionSort I need to pass comparator *c* to another function:

```
 less(input[j], input[j-1], c); // can I do so?
```

Here is my code:

```
struct Player
{
    int number;
    ulong efficiency;

    Player(int numb, ulong ef) : number(numb), efficiency(ef) {}
    Player() : number(0), efficiency(0) {}

    // functor for comparing players by efficiency 
    bool operator() (const Player &left, const Player &right)
    {
        return left.efficiency < right.efficiency;
    }
};

// template function for comparing various elements
template<typename T, typename Comp = std::less<T> >
bool less (const T &left, const T &right, Comp c = Comp())
{
    return c(left, right);
}

template <typename T>
void swap (T &a, T &b)
{
    T tempr = a;
    a = b;
    b = tempr;
}

template<typename T, typename Comp = std::less<T> >
void insertionSort (vector<T>& input, int begin, int end, Comp c = Comp())
{
    for (int i = begin; i <= end; ++i)
        for (int j = i; j > begin && less(input[j], input[j-1], c); --j)
            swap(input[j], input[j-1]);   
}
```

Now I have the following compilation error: **"default template arguments are only allowed on a class template"**  in function *less* and another template functions. Please, can you say, what I'm doing wrong? I can't find out where is my mistake. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably compiling in C++03 mode and default template arguments for functions are not allowed there. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447458/default-template-arguments-for-function-templates) for details. So if you want default template arguments, you can either switch to C++11 or use a functor instead of the function.

Using class `Player` as a comparator would work, but you have to instantiate it every time you call `insertionSort`, which is not for free as the class is not empty. It seems more efficient to have separate functor for comparing Players.

Also, you don't need to call `less` method in `insertionSort`, calling the comparator directly is enough. (`c(input[j], input[j-1])`).

Another solution would be to specialize `std::less<Player>` and use `std::less` for the comparison all the time. Please [refer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282349/specialization-of-templateclass-tp-struct-stdless-in-different-namespace).

Answer (score 0):

The message I got back clang makes it pretty clear.

"default template arguments for a function template are a C++11 extension."

This is a feature missing in C++98 which was later added in C++11.