# Invalid operands to binary expression (‘const Vector’ and ‘const Vector’)

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and I get this error “Invalid operands to binary expression (‘const Vector’ and ‘const Vector’)” and I have no idea where to look at in my own code.

The error appears at the line “{return __x < __y;}” in _functional_base:

```
    #if _LIBCPP_STD_VER > 11
template <class _Tp = void>
#else
template <class _Tp>
#endif
struct _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY less : binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool>
{
    _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_AFTER_CXX11 _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY 
    bool operator()(const _Tp& __x, const _Tp& __y) const
        {return __x < __y;}
};
```

But my real code looks like this:

```
//
//  MCP.cpp
//  Speciale
//
//  Created by Zaki G on 21/11/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Zaki G. All rights reserved.
//

#include "mcp.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Vector.h"
#include "Particle.h"
#include "Detector.h"
#include "Cave.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <map>




MCP::MCP(char* name,Vector& dimension,Vector& QuartzDimension, int NumberSubQuartz, double ElectronicThickness, double Reflective_index, double z_axis_sign): Detector(name, dimension, 0)
    {
    MCP_Dimension = dimension;
    MCP_QuartDimension = QuartzDimension;
    MCP_NumberSubQuartz = NumberSubQuartz;
    MCP_ElectronicThickness = ElectronicThickness;
    MCP_Quartz_Reflective_index = Reflective_index;
    MCP_z_axis_sign = z_axis_sign;
    }

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Vector MCP::Quartz_wall_Intersection(Detector& name, Vector &inter_front_quartz, Vector &path_photon, Vector &direction_vector, int reflection_on_off, Vector &Cherenkov_photon) //The direction vector is the vector against the normal vectors of the walls, and the Cherenkov_photon is only called to
                            //calculate the refelcted photon.

{             // Function for finding the intersection with the quartz walls and it can also calculated the reflected photon vector//

    Vector detector_posi = name.fPosition; // The position of the detector

    double Quartz_L_corner_x = detector_posi.GetX()-(0.053/2);
    double Quartz_L_corner_y = detector_posi.GetY()-(0.053/2);
    double Quartz_L_corner_z = detector_posi.GetZ();
    Vector loop_Quartz_Lcorner = (Quartz_L_corner_x, Quartz_L_corner_y, Quartz_L_corner_z); //The position of the Quartz down left corner.

    //Generating walls and roofs position for every sub MCP quartz.

    int number_of_walls =int(sqrt(MCP_NumberSubQuartz)); //4+1 walls in total remember "+1"

    int walls_position[number_of_walls+1];
    for (int i = 0; i<=number_of_walls; i++)
    {
        walls_position[i] = loop_Quartz_Lcorner.GetX()+i*(0.053/sqrt(MCP_NumberSubQuartz)); // 0.053 is the length and width of the MCP Quartz
    }

    int number_of_roof =int(sqrt(MCP_NumberSubQuartz));
    int roofs_position[number_of_roof+1];
    for (int i = 0; i<=number_of_roof; i++)
    {
        roofs_position[i] = loop_Quartz_Lcorner.GetY()+i*(0.053/sqrt(MCP_NumberSubQuartz));
    }

    //loop for which section (Divided quartz) is the generated particle close to.
    int en = 0;
    int to = 0;
    double x_array[2];
    double y_array[2];
    for (int i = 0; i<=number_of_walls; i++)
    {
        if ( abs(inter_front_quartz.GetX()) - abs(walls_position[i])<= (0.053/sqrt(MCP_NumberSubQuartz))){
            x_array[en] = walls_position[i];
            en =+1;
            if ( abs(inter_front_quartz.GetY()) - abs(roofs_position[i]) <= (0.053/sqrt(MCP_NumberSubQuartz))){
                y_array[to] = roofs_position[i];
                to =+1;
            }
        }
    }

    // Defining the four point in which the particle is incapsuled within the divided quartz:

    Vector position_array_one_zero = Vector(x_array[0], y_array[0], 0);
    Vector position_array_one_one = Vector(x_array[0], y_array[1], 0);
    Vector position_array_two_zero = Vector(x_array[1], y_array[0], 0);
    Vector position_array_two_one = Vector(x_array[1], y_array[1], 0);

    //Defining the four normal vectors for the incapsuled walls and roofs:

    //Walls normal vector:
    //Left:
    Vector normal_left = (position_array_one_one-position_array_one_zero).Cross(Vector(position_array_one_zero.GetX(),position_array_one_zero.GetY(),position_array_one_zero.GetZ()-0.020)-position_array_one_zero);

    //Right:
    Vector normal_right = (position_array_two_one-position_array_two_zero).Cross(Vector(position_array_two_zero.GetX(),position_array_two_zero.GetY(),position_array_two_zero.GetZ()-0.020)-position_array_two_one);


    //Roof normal vectors:
    //Top:
    Vector normal_top = (position_array_two_one-position_array_one_one).Cross(Vector(position_array_one_one.GetX(),position_array_one_one.GetY(),position_array_one_one.GetZ()-0.020)-position_array_one_one);
    //Bottom:
    Vector normal_bottom = (position_array_one_zero-position_array_two_zero).Cross(Vector(position_array_two_zero.GetX(),position_array_two_zero.GetY(),position_array_two_zero.GetZ()-0.020)-position_array_two_zero);


                                    // Putting the normal vectors in a array
    Vector normal_walls_roof[4]={normal_left,normal_right,normal_top,normal_bottom};


    //point on the surface for every normal vector which coresponds to the each surface
    map<Vector, Vector> quartz_surface_position;
    quartz_surface_position[normal_walls_roof[1]] =Vector(position_array_one_zero) + Vector(0, (0.053/8), (0.020/2)*MCP_z_axis_sign ) ; //Left
    quartz_surface_position[normal_walls_roof[2]] =Vector(position_array_two_zero) + Vector(0, (0.053/8), (0.020/2)*MCP_z_axis_sign ); //Right
    quartz_surface_position[normal_walls_roof[3]] =Vector(position_array_one_one)  + Vector((0.053/8), 0, (0.020/2)*MCP_z_axis_sign ); //Top
    quartz_surface_position[normal_walls_roof[4]] =Vector(position_array_two_one)  + Vector(-(0.053/8), 0, (0.020/2)*MCP_z_axis_sign );//Bottom

    Vector Quartz_wall_Intersection; //The intersection point on one of the walls

    Vector return_intersection_vector;

                                        //Looping over which wall it hits
    for (int i=0; i<=3; i++){
        double dot_normal = direction_vector.Dot(normal_walls_roof[i]);
        if (dot_normal < 10e-18)
        { //the dot product should be less than zero so the angle is stump (over 90 degree)

                                        //The intersection point on one of the walls
            Vector Quartz_wall_Intersection = path_photon-(((path_photon-quartz_surface_position[i]).Dot(normal_walls_roof[i])/dot_normal)*direction_vector);

            Vector w_quartz = Quartz_wall_Intersection - quartz_surface_position[i];

            // If the intersection of the plane falls outside window, return a
            // NAN vector.
            if (w_quartz.GetY() > name.GetHeight() || w_quartz.GetZ() > name.GetWidth())
            {
                return_intersection_vector =  Vector(NAN,NAN,NAN);
            }

            else
            {
                if (reflection_on_off==1) //If the reflected momentum is needed:
                {
                    // Refelction vector with in the quartz walls for the Cherenkov photons
                    Vector Reflection_vector_quartz = Cherenkov_photon -2.0*(Cherenkov_photon.Dot(normal_walls_roof[i]))*normal_walls_roof[i];
                    return_intersection_vector = Reflection_vector_quartz;
                }

                else
                {
                    return_intersection_vector = Quartz_wall_Intersection;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return return_intersection_vector;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


void MCP::Cherenkov_Photon_Generation(const Particle& pname, Vector &first_intersection, Vector &second_intersection, Vector pathPhoton_array[], Vector CherenkovPhoton_array[])
{
                            // Now we generates cherenkov photons along the particle path.//

    Vector particle_momentum = pname.GetMomentum();


    // The end_value is a constant, which describes the position where the particle is at the end of the quart plan.
    double end_value =(second_intersection.GetX()-first_intersection.GetX())/particle_momentum.GetX();

    // Generating the path for the particles where the photon should emits as Cherenkov light.


    for (int n=0; n<=1000; n++) //1000 Cherenkov photons per particle
    {
        srand( (unsigned int) time(0) );
        double random_number_d = ( double(rand()) / double(RAND_MAX))*end_value; // generate numbers between 0 and end_value.


        double path_photon_x =first_intersection.GetX() + random_number_d*particle_momentum.GetX();
        double path_photon_y =first_intersection.GetY() + random_number_d*particle_momentum.GetY();;
        double path_photon_z =first_intersection.GetZ() + random_number_d*particle_momentum.GetZ();

        Vector path_photon(path_photon_x,path_photon_y,path_photon_z);

        double random_angle = (rand()/RAND_MAX)* (2*M_PI); //Generate number between 0 and 2*Pi
        Vector velocity_vector = pname.GetVelocity();
        double v = velocity_vector.Length();

        double Cherenkov_Angle = acos((1.0)/(MCP_Quartz_Reflective_index*v));
        double x = (pname.GetMomentum()).Length()*sin(Cherenkov_Angle)*cos(random_angle); //random angle is from 0-2pi
        double y = (pname.GetMomentum()).Length()*sin(Cherenkov_Angle)*sin(random_angle);
        double z = (pname.GetMomentum()).Length()*cos(Cherenkov_Angle);

        Vector Cherenkov_photon(x,y,z);

        //pathPhoton_Cherenkov_array[path_photon] = Cherenkov_photon;
        pathPhoton_array[n] = path_photon;
        CherenkovPhoton_array[n] = Cherenkov_photon;

    }
    return;
}




//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



Vector MCP::MCP_end_Intersection_for_particle(const Particle& pname, Vector &particle_pos, Detector& name)
{
    // Intersection with the end surface of the quartz//

    // end_position is the position of the end plan of the quartz.
    Vector front_quartz_position = name.fPosition;

    Vector end_position(front_quartz_position.GetX(),front_quartz_position.GetY(),front_quartz_position.GetZ()+(0.020*MCP_z_axis_sign));

    Vector particle_momentum = pname.GetMomentum();

    Vector normal_end_quartz(0, 0, MCP_QuartDimension.GetX()*MCP_QuartDimension.GetY()*MCP_z_axis_sign);

    double dot_end_quartz = particle_momentum.Dot(normal_end_quartz);

    if (dot_end_quartz > 10e-18)
    {
        return Vector(NAN,NAN,NAN);
    }

    // inter_end_quartz is the intersection point on the end surface of the quartz
    Vector inter_end_quartz = particle_pos-(((particle_pos-end_position).Dot(normal_end_quartz)/dot_end_quartz)*particle_momentum);

    Vector w_end_quartz = inter_end_quartz - end_position;

    // If the intersection of the plane falls outside window, return a
    // Zero vector.
    if (w_end_quartz.GetX() > MCP_QuartDimension.GetX() || w_end_quartz.GetY() > MCP_QuartDimension.GetY())
    {
        return Vector(NAN,NAN,NAN);
    }
    return inter_end_quartz;
}


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Vector MCP::MCP_end_Intersection_for_Photon(Vector &Photon_momentum, Vector &particle_pos, Detector& name)
{
    // Intersection with the end surface of the quartz//

    // end_position is the position of the end plan of the quartz.
    Vector front_quartz_position = name.fPosition;

    Vector end_position(front_quartz_position.GetX(),front_quartz_position.GetY(),front_quartz_position.GetZ()+(0.020*MCP_z_axis_sign));

    Vector normal_end_quartz(0, 0, MCP_QuartDimension.GetX()*MCP_QuartDimension.GetY()*MCP_z_axis_sign);

    double dot_end_quartz = Photon_momentum.Dot(normal_end_quartz);

    if (dot_end_quartz > 10e-18)
    {
        return Vector(NAN,NAN,NAN);
    }

    // inter_end_quartz is the intersection point on the end surface of the quartz
    Vector inter_end_quartz = particle_pos-(((particle_pos-end_position).Dot(normal_end_quartz)/dot_end_quartz)*Photon_momentum);

    Vector w_end_quartz = inter_end_quartz - end_position;

    // If the intersection of the plane falls outside window, return a
    // Zero vector.
    if (w_end_quartz.GetX() > MCP_QuartDimension.GetX() || w_end_quartz.GetY() > MCP_QuartDimension.GetY())
    {
        return Vector(NAN,NAN,NAN);
    }
    return inter_end_quartz;
}



//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



void MCP::MCP_Intersection(const Particle& pname, Vector &particle_pos, Detector& name, Vector intersection_array[], int array_size)
{

    //Intersection with the front surface of the MCP which is the quartz.//

    Vector particle_momentum = pname.GetMomentum(); //Momentum of the particle

    Vector front_quartz_position = name.fPosition; // position of the MCP on the FIT  (Husk nedeunder MCP flad position)

    Vector normal_front_quartz(0,0,MCP_QuartDimension.GetY()*MCP_QuartDimension.GetX());

    double dot_front_quartz = particle_momentum.Dot(normal_front_quartz);

    if (dot_front_quartz > 10e-18)
    {
        //return Vector(NAN, NAN, NAN);
    }



    // inter_front_quartz is the intersection point on the quartz
    Vector inter_front_quartz = particle_pos-(((particle_pos-front_quartz_position).Dot(normal_front_quartz)/dot_front_quartz)*particle_momentum);

    Vector w = inter_front_quartz - front_quartz_position;

    // If the intersection of the plane falls outside window, return a
    // Zero vector.
    if (w.GetX() > name.GetHeight() || w.GetY() > name.GetWidth())
    {
        //return Vector(NAN,NAN,NAN);
    }



    //---------------------------------------------------------------------

                                // Intersection with the end surface of the quartz//

    // end_position is the position of the end plan of the quartz.  ---------.men hvad med protonen flyver den videre igennem MCP?!!!

    Vector end_position(front_quartz_position.GetX(),front_quartz_position.GetY(),front_quartz_position.GetZ()+(0.020*MCP_z_axis_sign));


    Vector normal_end_quartz(0, 0, MCP_QuartDimension.GetX()*MCP_QuartDimension.GetY()*MCP_z_axis_sign);

    double dot_end_quartz = particle_momentum.Dot(normal_end_quartz);

    if (dot_end_quartz > 10e-18) // If it does not intersect with the end panel, then it must intersect with the walls of the MCP.
    {
                                    //Here I find the wall intersection
        Vector zero_vector(NAN,NAN,NAN);

        Vector particle_intersection_with_wall = Quartz_wall_Intersection(name, inter_front_quartz, particle_pos , particle_momentum, 0 , zero_vector);

        //Defining the two arrays for path of the photons and the cherenkov photon vector:

        Vector pathPhoton_array[1000];
        Vector CherenkovPhoton_array[1000];

        Cherenkov_Photon_Generation(pname, inter_front_quartz, particle_intersection_with_wall, pathPhoton_array, CherenkovPhoton_array);

        //slette Vector array_path_cherenkov_photon = Cherenkov_Photon_Generation(pname, inter_front_quartz, particle_intersection_with_wall);

        static Vector intersection_array[1000];

                                    //Here it finds out that the photon intersect with the walls or not.
        for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(pathPhoton_array); i++)
        {
            Vector photon_intersection_with_wall = Quartz_wall_Intersection(name, inter_front_quartz, pathPhoton_array[i] , CherenkovPhoton_array[i], 0, zero_vector);



            if (photon_intersection_with_wall.GetX() != zero_vector.GetX()) //If the photon interc. with the wall:
            {
                // Here the reflected photon is found:
                Vector reflected_photon = Quartz_wall_Intersection(name, inter_front_quartz, pathPhoton_array[i] , CherenkovPhoton_array[i], 1, CherenkovPhoton_array[i]);

                //The reflected photon is intersected with MCP
                Vector intersection_with_end_MCP = MCP_end_Intersection_for_Photon(reflected_photon, photon_intersection_with_wall, name);

                intersection_array[i] = intersection_with_end_MCP;

                //return Intersection; // tænk lige over det

            }

            else // If the photon do not intersect with the wall then:
            {
                Vector intersection_with_end_MCP = MCP_end_Intersection_for_Photon(CherenkovPhoton_array[i], pathPhoton_array[i], name);

                //Intersection[] = intersection_with_end_MCP;

                intersection_array[i] = intersection_with_end_MCP;
                //return Intersection; // tænk lige over det
            }
        }
    }

    //The particle intersection with the MCP directly

    Vector intersection_with_end_MCP = MCP_end_Intersection_for_particle(pname, particle_pos, name);

    //Intersection[] = intersection_with_end_MCP; 

                                        //Generate Cherenkov photon in 2D array
    Vector pathPhoton_array[1000] = {};
    Vector CherenkovPhoton_array[1000] = {};

    Cherenkov_Photon_Generation(pname, inter_front_quartz, intersection_with_end_MCP, pathPhoton_array, CherenkovPhoton_array);

    Vector zero_vector(NAN,NAN,NAN);

    for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(CherenkovPhoton_array); i++)
    {
        Vector photon_intersection_with_wall = Quartz_wall_Intersection(name, inter_front_quartz, pathPhoton_array[i], CherenkovPhoton_array[i], 0, zero_vector);
        if (photon_intersection_with_wall.GetX()!= NAN) //If the photon interc. with the wall:
        {
            // Here the reflected photon is found:
            Vector reflected_photon = Quartz_wall_Intersection(name, inter_front_quartz, pathPhoton_array[i] , CherenkovPhoton_array[i], 1, CherenkovPhoton_array[i]);

            //The reflected photon is intersected with MCP
            Vector intersection_with_end_MCP = MCP_end_Intersection_for_Photon(reflected_photon, photon_intersection_with_wall, name);


            intersection_array[i] = intersection_with_end_MCP;
        }

        else
        {
            Vector intersection_with_end_MCP = MCP_end_Intersection_for_Photon(CherenkovPhoton_array[i], pathPhoton_array[i], name);

            intersection_array[i] = intersection_with_end_MCP;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope someone can figure this out.

```
#ifndef _VECTOR_H
#define _VECTOR_H

//class ostream;
using namespace std;

class Vector 
{
private:
  double fX;
  double fY;
  double fZ;
public:
  Vector(double x=0, double y=0, double z=0);

  double Length(void) const;
  void   SetX(double x) { fX= x; }
  void   SetY(double y) { fY= y; }
  void   SetZ(double z) { fZ= z; }
  double GetX(void) const { return fX; }
  double GetY(void) const { return fY; }
  double GetZ(void) const { return fZ; }

  Vector Cross(const Vector& v) const;
  double Dot(const Vector& v) const;

  Vector operator+(const Vector& v);
  Vector operator-(const Vector& v);
  Vector operator=(const Vector& v);



    bool operator() (const Vector& lhs, const Vector& rhs) const
    {
        return (lhs.GetX(),lhs.GetY(),lhs.GetZ()) < (rhs.GetX(),rhs.GetY(),rhs.GetZ());
    }



}
;

// Global functions 
Vector operator*(const double  a, const Vector& v);
Vector operator*(const Vector& v, const Vector& u);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Vector& v);

#endif
```

Comment: I created a class called Vector : (double x, double y,double z)

Comment: and you define `operator <` for it?

Comment: The error message is clear, there's no `operator<` for `Vector`.

Comment: No I haven’t..But it doesn’t makes sense since vector.GetX() should just return a double number...

Comment: Which line did you get the error? You should provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The error doesn’t appear on my code but appears on the  “The LLVM Compiler Infrastructure” on the line “ {return __x < __y;}"

Comment: You are calling some method, that require defined `operator<` for its arguments. I think, its logical error, because for vectors only comparasion by module makes sence. Try to find such method and rewrite that in other way.

Comment: thanks I will try :-)

Comment: std::map requires operator <， but your vector did not define it. You should define one with bool return type.

Comment: The `vector` tag is not for mathematical vectors but for grow-able array like containers, removed the tag.

Comment: you mean Vector tag on :                                                                                         bool operator() (const Vector& lhs, const Vector& rhs) const
    {
        return (lhs.GetX(),lhs.GetY(),lhs.GetZ()) < (rhs.GetX(),rhs.GetY(),rhs.GetZ());
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as pointed out in the last comment, is `map<Vector, Vector>`. This is a sorted associative container. Its `Key` is a `Vector`, and the default order is `std::less<Vector>`.  The compiler duly instantiates `std::less<Vector>`, finds no specializations, and fails on `<`. You'll need to provide one, but it can be simple: `return std::tie(r.x, r.y, r.z) < std::tie(l.x, l.y, l.z)`.

PS. `normal_walls_roof[]` runs from `[0]` to `[3]`, not `[1]` to `[4]`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. when you say  “You'll need to provide one, but it can be simple: return std::tie(r.x, r.y, r.z) < std::tie(l.x, l.y, l.z).” Do you mean that I should provide it in the class description of Vector?

Comment: He means specialise `std::less<Vector>` to do what you want.    Read up documentation to work out how.

Comment: explicitly specializing `std::less` is much cleaner than overloading `operator <` . Good answer!

Comment: I have trying to explicitly specializing std::less, but i dont know how to do it..

Comment: @zack_ii: Not surprisingly, the answer is already on StackOverflow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282349/specialization-of-templateclass-tp-struct-stdless-in-different-namespace